# SSAS MDX Problem with IIF and TAIL() function

Tags: mdx, analysisservices

Experts,

I am using SQL SSAS Std. 2017 and in the end want to create a calculated member that returns either the last month's day of my data or the current day if the last existing data is of today.
(=> If today is Aug-31 I want to retrieve Aug-31 of my data, otherwise if today is e.g. Aug-30 retrieve Jul-31)

To develop this member I am currently in the process of creating a MDX query in SQL Server. I am having difficulties to understand what is actually a "tuple set expression" (because the TAIL() function shall return a subset (ergo set) according to MSDN) but in fact I am receiving errors when playing around with the .Item(0) function on its result. In MSDN I cannot find information about "tuple sets" and how to make them do, what I want.

My Date Dimension has a Hierarchy JMT (Year | Month | Day | Date Key of type DATE).

To receive the most current date member of the cross product I am using the TAIL(NONEMPTY(Date...Members, { (DimX.&.. , DimY.&.. , DimZ.&..) })) expression which works fine.

But how do I choose between today's or the previous month's date?

My MDX for testing purposes on February (2) is as follows:

```
        SELECT { 
        IIF(
            TAIL(NONEMPTY([DateDim].[JMT].[T].Members, { ([DimX].[X].&[200], [DimY].[Company].&[4499166], [DateDim].[JMT].[M].&[2020]&[2]) })).Item(0) --.Properties('Date Key', TYPED)
            > NOW()
            , TAIL(NONEMPTY([DateDim].[JMT].[T].Members, { ([DimX].[X].&[200], [DimY].[Company].&[4499166], [DateDim].[JMT].[M].&[2020]&[1]) }))
            , TAIL(NONEMPTY([DateDim].[JMT].[T].Members, { ([DimX].[X].&[200], [DimY].[Company].&[4499166], [DateDim].[JMT].[M].&[2020]&[2]) }))
            )
--      , 
--      TAIL(NONEMPTY([DateDim].[JMT].[T].Members, { ([DimX].[X].&[200], [DimY].[Company].&[4499166], [DateDim].[JMT].[M].&[2020]&[2]) })) } on columns  
    , { [Measures].[Turnover] } on rows
    FROM [Finance]
```

Result:
[image: Result]

As you can see, the IIF function does not do what I want. It assumes .Item(0) is greater than NOW() therefore returning the "31" member of January (1). Expected: "29" of February.

I guess, it might be a problem with the data types and the actual value returned by .Item(0). But if I want to use the .Properties('Date Key', TYPED) it states "The Date Key Dimension Attribute could not be found. See below picture.

[image]
In the image of the DateDim it should be "DateDim.JMT" in the blue area ;-).

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you, Cordt

Answer (score 0):

If you switch this:

```
TAIL(NONEMPTY([DateDim].[JMT].[T].Members, { ([DimX].[X].&[200], [DimY].[Company].&[4499166], [DateDim].[JMT].[M].&[2020]&[2]) })).Item(0)
```

to the following does it help?

```
Tail
(
  NonEmpty
  (
    [DateDim].[JMT].[T].MEMBERS
   ,{
      (
        [DimX].[X].&[200]
       ,[DimY].[Company].&[4499166]
       ,[DateDim].[JMT].[M].&[2020]&[2]
      )
    }
  )
).Item(0).Item(0).MemberValue
```

Comment: Sadly doesn't solve my problem but it is giving me new ideas and a better understanding so thank you for your reply :-)